# Rendering a node that is not part of the JCR

Tags: magnolia

I would like to render a page that is not in the JCR store. I have the page structure in a file. We are running Magnolia 5.6.13 and according to [this](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS56/Rendering+content) it is possible to do it but I am unclear how. Is it the RenderingModelImpl#getContent that I have to overwrite or is it an AbstractRenderer class method that I have to overwrite?
Thanks,
Ana

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you have in the file you are trying to load/render? Just HTML or freemarker template or template made by some other templating language or is it actually representation of page that you would normally have in JCR just coming from file instead of from JCR? I presume it's the last one. If that is the case and you want to make use of what Magnolia provides ootb as much as possible, you need to override `getContent()` method, load your file in that method and create `Content` object to be returned by the method (might want to use `MockContent` from `magnolia-core-test` jar for testing this). Basically turn your file representation of the page into content.

`AbstractRenderer` should be overwritten only when you are attempting to replace templating language or kind of output that Rendering Engine produces, not when you are trying to feed it different input.

Comment: Thanks @Jan 
Yes it is the last one, representing a page that would normally render from JCR just coming from a file instead of from JCR. Exactly the way you said it, I need to return a new Content object that I somehow build in memory.

Comment: Hi @Jan Can you please elaborate what you meant when you wrote to use MockContent from magnolia-core-test.

Comment: There is a class used by tests that implements the ```javax.jcr.Content``` interface called ```MockContent``` that you can fill with the info from your file-based page structure. That's all. For production use you would however want to use your own implementation of the ```Content``` interface anyway, so if you don't know where to find it  and how to add magnolia-core-test.jar to your build then you can just go ahead and make your own implementation of it.